# How to set config properties for reading trained data sets from disk in datumbox framework?

Tags: java, machine-learning, config, datumbox

I'm doing the sentiment analysis using datumbox framework.In the code examples of datumbox the trained examples for sentiment analysis are taken from the resource folder containing the pos and neg sentences [HERE IS THE EXAMPLE CODE.](https://github.com/datumbox/datumbox-framework-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datumbox/examples/TextClassification.java)

For getting better accuracy we need to have more and more trained examples we just can't load all the data from a file right ? Now I want to take that data from disk but unable to find out how to fix config propeties in the config file of datumbox to get trained examples from disk.

In the code example we are taking trained examples from files as follows.

```
Map<Object, URI> datasets = new HashMap<>(); //The examples of each category are stored on the same file, one example per row.
datasets.put("positive", TextClassification.class.getClassLoader().getResource("datasets/sentiment-analysis/rt-polarity.pos").toURI());
datasets.put("negative", TextClassification.class.getClassLoader().getResource("datasets/sentiment-analysis/rt-polarity.neg").toURI());
```

Once we are able to read training data from disk how to replace the above three lines in code ?

can any one of you help me out?

Here is the [blog](http://blog.datumbox.com/datumbox-machine-learning-framework-0-7-0-released/%20here%20is%20the%20code%20link) that tells about disk based training :

[here is the link of config Settings](https://github.com/datumbox/datumbox-framework-examples/blob/master/src/main/resources/datumbox.config.properties)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your problem completely mostly because of my bad English I guess. But if I am right I think you are trying to make the properties find the path to the disk to add the files you need. You can try making specific fields in the *conf* folder on property file like `properpath=C://desktop/neededfile` etc.Then you can call it using the `java.util.Properties` and later you use the correct `FileInputStream`-like class that can read your files correctly. For example:

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(source.properpath);
```

I use the code I show you to read xml files, different kind of files but still same basic principle. I hope it helped you.

Comment: I don't think that person is asking this? he wanted to read the data from the disk(i.e any db table) for that he is asking about changing of config file for connection and code lines that he need to change.@SlothProgrammer